# Generate an unique word list from a word list of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator

See the following data. I want to obtain an unique word list from it.
I prepared the following base code for you. Could someone improve the code for better and faster performance in Python 3.X?

```
data = [
    [
        ['hello'],
        ['hi', 'top'],
        ['how', 'are', 'you']
    ],
    [
        ['hey', 'jane'],
        ['good', 'morning'],
        ['how', 'are', 'you']
    ]
]
vocab = []
for d in data:
    for s in d:
        for w in s:
            if w not in vocab:
                vocab.append(w)
vocab = sorted(vocab)
print(vocab) # ['are', 'good', 'hello', 'hey', 'hi', 'how', 'jane', 'morning', 'top', 'you']
```

Comment: Hope someone modifies the title..

Comment: Are all words two levels deep?

Comment: `sorted(set(w for d in data for s in d for w in s))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the elements are *hashable* (strings *are* hashable), it is usually *not* a good idea to do uniqueness checks yourself. Python has already designed a construct for this: a `set`. A set guarantees that every *equal* element occurs *at most* once (so it occurs once, or not at all).

We can feed a `set(..)` an iterable, like for instance a generator that will generate the words, and after the set is constructed we can (optionally) sort the elements in the set, so:

```
sorted(set(w for d in data for s in d for w in s))
```

So here we first construct a `set` of the elements yielded by the generator `(w for d in data for s in d for w in s)` (which is basically a compact representation of your cascaded `for` loops). A `set` uses hashing and as a result it can check membership quite fast. Next we iterate over the `set(..)` and sort the elements that are yielded.

Modern versions of Python also support *set comprehension*: we can merge `set(<generator-expr>)` into `{<generator-expr>}`, this is nicer syntactically, but will usually also achieve some speedup, so:

```
sorted({w for d in data for s in d for w in s})
```

Comment: Although I knew `set`, I didn't realize the difference between `set` and self-uniqueness. Thank you. Your code looks reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

[`more_itertools.collapse`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.collapse) flattens deeply nested lists, from you can get unique words via `set()`.

```
import more_itertools as mit


set(mit.collapse(data))
# {'are', 'good', 'hello', 'hey', 'hi', 'how', 'jane', 'morning', 'top', 'you'}
```

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third party package.  Install via `> pip install more_itertools`.

Comment: Oh, I've never heard `more_itertools`. Looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use set comprehension in recursion:

```
data = [
[
    ['hello'],
    ['hi', 'top'],
    ['how', 'are', 'you']
],
[
    ['hey', 'jane'],
    ['good', 'morning'],
    ['how', 'are', 'you']
  ]
]
def get_unique(s):
  return {i for c in [b if all(isinstance(d, str) for d in b) else get_unique(b) for b in s] for i in c}
print(list(get_unique(data)))
```

Output:

```
['good', 'top', 'hey', 'morning', 'how', 'hi', 'are', 'jane', 'you', 'hello']
```